# The plausibility of Orcs developing advanced prosthesis

Tags: fantasy-races, technological-development

### The Context

Despite their seeming barbarity of the Orcs of my world they have developed prosthetics that rival that of modern non-electrical prosthetics.

Relevant information on the Orcs

- It is not uncommon for an Orc to cut off one or more of their limbs in order to replace it with a prosthetic that has iron in it, so fairies can not manipulate their limbs with their magic.
- Orcs are experts when it comes to working with iron.
- The Orcs general tech level is that of the early medieval Britain.
- The average Orc is dumb but creative.
- The Orcs' prosthetics are commonly akin to that athletes use.

### The Question

Is it believable that these dumb orcs are able create prosthetics that rival modern non-electric prosthetics?

Comment: Are they meant to be functional, aka, not the equivalent of an unmoving and mostly aesthetic mannequin-like body part?

Comment: @Lemming the prosthetics are functional and capable of movement, like something akin to a claw arm and a spring leg.

Comment: What do you believe "rivaling modern non-electric prostheses" to mean? You should duct-tape a hook to your elbow and then go try to cook dinner with just that (you can use the other hand). You'll find that you're really clumsy with it, and that even after you spent the time to learn to use it well, it in no way replaces the limb itself. In such steampunk fantasies where things like that happen, there's alot of handwavium going on. Literally no one would ever amputate a functioning limb for even the prostheses available today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

1. Technology (mechanisms) required - as per the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthesis), "During the Renaissance, prosthetics developed with the use of iron, steel, copper, and wood. Functional prosthetics began to make an appearance in the 1500s."  No matter how creative an individual orc may be, the techniques and materials required (eg clockwork mechanisms) simply were not available in the early medieval period.
2. More technology (materials) required - modern athletic limbs rely on lightweight, modern materials with precisely determined amounts of spring and carefully designed grip.  Medieval materials were not up to the job - even trying to maintain balance with fully functional legs could be problematic in the primitive footwear available, as per [this](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiEu8664ab2AhVMTWwGHc7CCLgQtwJ6BAgDEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D-3qTniJsoEg&usg=AOvVaw3Q2PSqk_SUi1UluMLm9cxo) video - no materials of the time were as good at gripping on a variety of surfaces as human/orc skin.  It would be simply impossible to try to make an iron/steel leg that would allow the user to run at all effectively, let alone at the speeds achieved using carbon-fibre-reinforced polymers.
3. Loss of sense of touch / loss of strength - there is no way to compensate for losing the sense of touch with a primitive mechanical limb, the most that might be achieved is a single sensor that presses into the stump to give a single indicator whether anything is being touched.  Similarly, there is no way to compensate for the loss of the muscles in the amputated limb, making the amputee less strong than a non-amputee, even modern, powered limbs struggle to approach biological limb performance.  Unlike the other factors, these do not make prostheses impossible, just inferior in performance.  (I have no intention of offending any amputees out there and I recognise that there are some amputees who can outperform non-amputees in some tasks.)
4. Survivability - given the fatality rate in armies due to infection from much less serious injuries than an amputation, I suspect that even if "Orcs is tough!" the vast majority of orc amputees would die from infection and sepsis within a week of amputation.  For those that did survive the initial process, infection from post-op chafing of the stump would kill more off shortly afterwards - see again the issues with the materials available.
5. Unnecessary for protection - if fairies somehow have the capability to manipulate limbs then put iron around or in the limbs.  Wear armour, or iron bracelets/rings/anklets.  Go for iron piercings if necessary, although it's probably a good idea to coat the iron with something less reactive first eg silver or gold.  However, the whole amputation-to-avoid-limb-control idea seems to be a very weak rationale - if the fairies can manipulate normal orc flesh then it would be much less effort to close an orc's eyelids to render him blind, or stop his breathing / heart than it would be to move an entire limb.